# polymorphic and one-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a Collaboration model with a polymorphic association with a Grade | School, and a one-to-many association with a User

```
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "teacher_id"
```

this is the way i manage the users who can access a school or a grade. Now, what i need is to do something like this

```
School.first.teachers 
Grade.first.teachers
```

I think it would be something like this in the Grade/School model

```
has_many :teachers, through: :collaborations, foreign_key: "teacher_id"
```

but it doesn't seem to be the right solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_many :collaborations, :as => :owner
has_many :teachers, :through => :collaborations, :source => :user
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish the polymorphic association to collaborations. Try:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collaborations, :as => :owner
  has_many :teachers, :through => :collaborations
end
```

Comment: Like Babur Usenakunov said in the previous post, i need source: :user too . :) Thanks for your answer